# Настройка параметров картинки (яркость, контраст, гамма)

Tags: opensuse, ati, linux

Добрый день.Подскажите возможно ли производить такие настройки с открытым драйвером?Так это выглядит в [закрытом драйвере](http://s8.postimage.org/7q07ts9z9/image.png). Может есть какие то консольные утилиты для этого?Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для правильной тонкой настройки параметров видеокарточки нужны именно проприетарные дрова, и только! Потому, что они от производителя. И только производитель может знать, чего он в эту карту засунул. GPL драйвера используют стандартный минимум функционала. В консольном текстовом режиме я вообще не понимаю зачем это нужно - проще монитор настроить!

Comment: Эхх если бы это было так просто я бы и вопросов не задавал. На мониторе нет регулировок. А производитель перестал поддерживать мою видео карту (radeon hd 2400 xt) в новых дистрибутивах linux.

Comment: "на мониторе нет регулировок".. какая модель монитора?

Comment: Это ноутбук acer TravelMate 5520G.

Comment: А вот это не подойдёт? http://driver.ru/_103297496610a428541f0f0aa434/Скачать-ATI-Radeon-HD-2400-XT-VGA-Драйвер-v.12.4-для-RedHat-5-6-7-8-9-SUSE-Linux-x86-Ubuntu-бесплатноУвы, сам проверить не могу - у меня NVIDIA везде!

Comment: Не знаю, надо попробовать. Спасибо за ссылку. Вообще на сайте amd написано что новые ядра linux не поддерживаются, так что вряд ли появятся новые драйвера. Я больше на открытый расчитывал